# Compare time give in each li with Current Time

Tags: javascript, jquery

**What is this about ?**

I am trying to check if the current time is less then or equal to the time given in particular span

---

**What's the issue ?**

I want to set timer for each li without page refresh to check if the time is equal to current time or time given in span is less then 2 second comparing with the current time. I am not sure what's the good practise to check this for individual li ?

---

**Html**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="hidden time">December 3 2015 21:58:00 UTC-0800</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="hidden time">December 12 2015 15:00:00 UTC-0800</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: there are errors in the fiddle pls fix it

Comment: you haven't included JS in your fiddle.

Comment: if included there will be another error function moment not defined

Comment: Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x6s7rnu6/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One counter would do just fine. You would want to set the interval to something less than 2 seconds and at each interval use the jQuery `.filter()` method to see if there're any spans with a time meeting the condition and then add the class.

```js
$(function() {
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        var ts = Date.now();
        $('.current').text( new Date(ts) );
        $('ul > li > .hidden.time').filter(function() {
            var thisTime = new Date( $(this).text().trim() );
            return thisTime - ts <= 2000;
        })
        .addClass('active');
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.active {
    background: black;
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Current Time: <span class="current"></span>
</div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="hidden time">December 3 2015 21:58:00 UTC-0800</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="hidden time">December 12 2015 15:00:00 UTC-0800</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```